# Obter Type de uma classe sem instanciá-la

Tags: c#, .net, classes, tipagem

Preciso obter o `Type` de uma classe sem instanciá-la, eu tentei fazer dessa forma:

```
variavelQualquer.Type = new ClasseA().Type; // Type é uma variável pública que guarda o valor do método GetType()
```

Mas assim ainda é criada uma instância (visto como foi feito, é o esperado mesmo). Como obter o tipo da classe sem que isso aconteça? É possível?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em geral não faz muito sentido você querer saber o tipo de uma classe, afinal o tipo desta classe é a própria classe. Pelo menos não faz sentido obter isto no exemplo mostrado. Ou seja, o tipo da classe `ClasseA` é `ClasseA`. Está óbvio no código.

Se você estiver em uma situação onde não é tão óbvio, usando reflexão, por exemplo, tem algumas alternativas.

Pode ser usar o operador [`typeof`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast#typeof-operator?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) que é resolvido em tempo de compilação:

```
Type t = typeof(Ns.Classe);
```

Pode usar o método [`GetType()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.gettype?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-6.0#System_Type_GetType_System_String_) no tipo sem criar uma instância. Só tome o cuidado de usar o nome completo do tipo com o `namespace` (resolvido em tempo de execução):

```
Type t = Type.GetType("Ns.Classe");
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Reflection/GetTypeTypeof.cs).