# Como obter as propriedades de um tipo quando utilizo Generics C#

Tags: c#, .net, reflexão, genéricos, propriedade

Tenho a seguinte classe:

```
public class Pessoa
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataNascimento { get; set; }
}
```

Desenvolvi um método para obter as propriedades dela, mas não estou conseguindo usar da maneira que quero:

```
public static class Entities<TEntidade> where TEntidade : class
{
    /* Assim da certo mas não quero passar por parametro */
    public static PropertyInfo[] GetPropertiesComoNaoQuero(TEntidade e)
    {         
        var entity = Activator.CreateInstance(e.GetType()) as TEntidade;
        PropertyInfo[] properties = entity.GetType().GetProperties();
        return properties;
    }

    public static PropertyInfo[] GetPropertiesComoEUQuero()
    {         
        /* 
         * Existe alguma forma de criar essa instancia sem passar por *parametro? so sabendo que o 
         * tipo generico meu é do tipo pessoa na chamada ? 
         */
        var entity = Activator.CreateInstance() as TEntidade;
        PropertyInfo[] properties = entity.GetType().GetProperties();
        return properties;
    }
}

public class Teste
{
    PropertyInfo[] properties = Entities<Pessoa>.GetPropertiesComoEUQuero();

    Pessoa pessa = new Pessoa();
    PropertyInfo[] propertiesb = Entities<Pessoa>.GetPropertiesComoNaoQuero(pessa);

}
```

Comment: Não sei se consigo entender qual o objetivo. Você quer instanciar uma `Pessoa` dentro do método `Inserir`?

Comment: Acho que agora deu pra entender, veja se era o que queria na minha resposta.

Comment: Você quer criar uma instância de um objeto só para pegar as propriedades dele por reflection? Se for isso não seria só usar um `typeof(TEntidade).GetProperties()`? Não vejo o porque precisa da instância da classe ai.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

É possível usando o operador [`typeof`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/75440/101). Veja a [diferença para o `GetType()`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/9661/101).

Não sei se realmente precisa fazer isso, o código fica tão simples que nem precisaria desse método, menos ainda de outra classe. Claro que pode desejar fazer uma abstração, mas precisa ter um motivo pra fazer.

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

public class Program {
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        var pessoa = new Pessoa { id = 1, Nome = "Nicola Bogar Uccio", DataNascimento = new DateTime(1988, 08, 24) };
        PropertyInfo[] properties = Entities<Pessoa>.GetPropertiesComoEUQuero();
    }
}

public class Pessoa {
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataNascimento { get; set; }
}

public static class Entities<TEntidade> where TEntidade : class {
    public static PropertyInfo[] GetPropertiesComoEUQuero() => typeof(TEntidade).GetProperties();
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/6V68fG). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ifis4d). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Reflection/GetGenericType.cs).

Comment: Obrigado amigo, isso que eu precisava.

Answer (score 7):

Na verdade nem é necessário outro método pra fazer isto, um simples `GetProperties()` usando `typeof` já adiantaria.

```
var properties = typeof(Pessoa).GetProperties();
```

Mesmo se quiser seguir na ideia dos genéricos, não é necessária essa passagem de parâmetro uma vez que você já tem o tipo em `TEntidade`.

```
public static class Entities<TEntidade> where TEntidade : class 
{
    public static PropertyInfo[] GetPropertiesComoEuQuero() 
    {         
        return typeof(TEntidade).GetProperties();
    }
}
```